# my project use proxy to cross domain，but when i request its request address change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, proxy, window

### can't cross domain

http://localhost:8080/api/login become http://localhost:8080/index.html

```
proxyTable: {
    '/api': {
        target: 'http://47.106.74.67:8080',
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
            '^/api': '/'
        }
    }
},
```

why?
i try to change all devServer in webpack.dev.conf.js,and i can't find dealing in   nerwork

Answer (score 1):

The following config would take you to http://47.106.74.67:8080/login
for http://localhost:8080/api/login.

```
proxyTable: {
    '/api': {
        target: 'http://47.106.74.67:8080',
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
            '^/api': ''
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to forward to http://47.106.74.67:8080/api/login then remove the `pathRewrite` config. The docs @ [vue-webpack-proxy](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/proxy.html) and [http-proxy-middleware#options](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#options)